# In a Turbo repo, how to import a local build of an external package from an internal package?

Tags: turborepo

I'm working on the structure for a monorepo using Turbo repo.

If I have this:

```
packages/
  development/
    dev-packageA/  // This is a mock for dev that consumes packageA
  packageA/        // PackageA is external. It gets deployed
    build/
```

My question is:

Can I import `packageA` inside `dev-packageA` and get it from `packageA/build` instead of having to publish a new version of `packageA` every time I want to test my dev mocks?

Answer (score 0):

I would check out the turbo repo docs section [Workspaces which depend on each other](https://turbo.build/repo/docs/handbook/workspaces#workspaces-which-depend-on-each-other).

```js
{
  "dependencies": {
    "shared-utils": "workspace:*"
  }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).